# ScrollView contentOffset reset after pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview, tableview, push

I'm experiencing a problem with ScrollView, my scrollView has 640 of width, from 0 to 320 it's a mapView, from 320 to 640 it's a tableView.
I have a segmentedButton with 2 options to switch my view from contentOffset from 0 to 320 in x.
The problem is, if I switch to contentOffset of 320 in x and press a cell of tableView, after releasing the button to push other viewController, the contentOffset of my scrollView is reseting to 0 in x. I need to keep contentOffset on the tableView, at 320 in x.
I tried many things, like playing around with viewWillDisappear and the lifecycle methods.
The closest I've been able to reach was making it going back to the tableView after pressing back. Although, I couldn't make it stay on the tableView to push the next viewController.

Any help is appreciated!

(Ps: I've search for similar questions, but the only one that could help, I couldn't understand very well, the others have similar but different problems).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
Here is the solution:
1. I'm doing content offset backup in viewWillDisappear
2. Restoring offset without animation in viewWillAppear.

UPDATE: Be sure you are not adjusting contentSize in viewWillLayoutSubviews or in methods mentioned above.

Comment: Didn't try yet, but sounds like a solution, I'll put as accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have very similar problem with UItableView which is also UIScrollView, but vertical.
Playing with viewWillDisappear: does not work because there is a noticeable scroll made by iOS when user initiated a push of another VC.

Can't resolve this problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Saving `contentOffset` backup at `viewWillDisappear` is not the correct way of handling which make you even worse to handle if you have some views which required show/hide on `viewWillAppear`.

The best way is saving the `contentOffset` at `scrollViewDidScroll`

> 1. Declare the variable where you want to save offset

```
var previousOffsetY: CGFloat = 0.0
var offsetLimitation: CGFloat = 50.0 // is the limit where I want to play show/hide
```

> 2. Inside `UIScrollViewDelegate` which is `scrollViewDidScroll`, save the offset.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        previousOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            if offset <= self.offsetLimitation {
                // show
            } else {
                // hide
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> 3. At `viewWillAppear`, control the UI you want when offset is reseted.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if previousOffsetY > offsetLimitation {
        // hide
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your scrollview frame when push to a new controller, if scrollview frame changed, scrollview will reset it's contentOffset